# Create svg element based on string via javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there an easy way to convert an string to svg element in vanilla javascript (no libraries)? Like:

```
var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>';

//convert this string to a DOM element
```

**Update**

I solved that by using the DOMParser API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

```
var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>';

function createSVGElement(data) {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var doc = parser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");
  document.body.appendChild(doc.lastChild);
}
```

It worked really well, and I don' have to use a div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a placeholder element, set the `innerHTML`, then get the `firstChild`

```
var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
placeholder.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>';
var elem = placeholder.firstChild;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
document.body.appendChild(div)
div.innerHTML = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M5 3l3.057-3 11.943 12-11.943 12-3.057-3 9-9z"/></svg>'
```